# Running jar reacts differently than running in Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, cmd, jira-rest-api

I am working on a project in Spring boot using maven.
First of all let me tell you, in intellij everything runs perfectly and I can open the website, BUT:
Now I have to create a test environment, so I generated a Jar using maven.
I have selected the right spring profile and now i'm running the jar with this command in command line:

```
java -jar .\pegusapps-dashboard-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=ext-api-dev,dev
```

When i run this, spring boot starts up and starts doing the normal stuff like in intellij, but when they are compiling the part where we use a rest api. It gives me this error:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.pegusapps.dashboard.integration.tempo.TempoServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.pegusapps.dashboard.integration.tempo.TempoRestApi' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pegusapps.dashboard.integration.tempo.TempoRestApi' in your configuration.
```

Let me explain the structure of the api. ( it is a jira rest api )

- We work with an interface that does all the calls to the rest api.
- Then we have a interface for the api service layer.
- And then we have the service implementation where they access the interface that does all the calls to the api.

Inside of the implementation of the service, we autowire the first interface in the constructor and that's where the error comes from ( from the cmd window ).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you check what command does intellij-idea execute when running the the jar? It should be on top of the console output.

Comment: @krizajb it runs a really long command and what I can make from it, is that it adds all of the dependencies to the command line.

Comment: It looks like you are not creating the jar with spring-boot-maven-plugin. That plugin creates a fat jar with all the dependencies.

Comment: @cool that is indeed the answer, I have found this on the web and will now try that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try building your JAR using *Apache Maven Shade Plugin*, like below.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using already use following

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```